# How to use \n in junction with a printed string literal?

Tags: java, string, escaping, bluej

I have to print a few lines of code using only string literals, escape sequences, and `System.out.print`. I am not allowed to use `System.out.println` or any other new line code except for `\n`. That said, how do I use `\n` in junction with printed string literals? Every time I try the following code:

```
System.out.print(row01\n);
```

bluej says `"illegal character: '\' "`. So how do I use `\n` in a printed statement without using quotes? I don't want to literally print `"row01"`, `row01` holds a string value. Again, I *have to use* `\n`. I'm not looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

You have to surround `\n` in quotes for it to be a valid newline character. So change:

```
System.out.print(row01\n);
```

To:

```
System.out.print(row01 + "\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; exactly what I was looking for. My course didn't say anything about needing to put quotes around escape sequences... will add that to my notes.